# glob.glob returns empty list when passed a variable

Tags: python

glob.glob returns an empty list when passed a variable, instead of absolute path. But when I type in the complete absolute path, it works fine. Following is my code. Any workaround for this:

```
import os
import glob
excelfolders_path = os.getcwd()
files = glob.glob('excelfolders_path/*/export_dashboard_*_*')
print files
```

Comment: Does the variable have the absolute or relative path? Check the value of the variable to see if it is valid.

Comment: @clinomaniac the variable has absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a relative path, you need to prepend `./` first. It's not python specific, it's Linux related.

`files = glob.glob('./excelfolders_path/*/export_dashboard_*_*')`

EDIT:
Just noticed that `excelfolders_path` is a variable. You can't use it like that, to render a variable in a string, you have to do something like that:
`files = glob.glob('{}/*/export_dashboard_*_*'.format(excelfolders_path))`

or

`files = glob.glob('./*/export_dashboard_*_*')`

Both should do the job, the first will use the absolute path and the second the relative path.

Comment: thanks for the response but still returning an empty list